# Is there a way to manually adjust ClearType in Windows without "choosing which looks best"?

Tags: windows, windows-10, cleartype

In Windows you can adjust the ClearType settings (with the ClearType Text Tuner) but to my knowledge there is no way to manually tweak them (as in moving some bars or something), you are only given these screens asking which font looks the best (reminds me of the eye doctor).

[image: ClearType]

I would rather manually adjust whatever it is these boxes are tweaking but I don't know if there is a way.

I recently switched to Windows 10 and the default settings just didn't seem to look right to me and no matter how I tweak them I can't seem to get them correct. Curves seem to look more jagged and things seem to "bleed" over into the next pixel more than they should.

---

For those who are unaware, ClearType uses the subpixels (as in the red, green, and blue portions of the pixel) to better render text than standard anti-aliasing alone.

Comment: this might be the fault of graphic drivers and/or some windows-10 dialog scaling.win-10 is a bit of a stylistic mess and some of the dialogs are bitmaps scaled up, which do not get touched by Cleartype. Some MS software uses greyscale smoothing instead of subpixel, and then browsers can be set to use different type rendering. For the GPU driver side: I know that AMD/ATI used to enable overscan scaling for monitors when attached via HDMI, which causes minor quality issues especially with the windows UI type

Comment: I am using an NVidia GTX 780 through an HDMI for what it is worth. Thanks for the insight, hadn't considered it might have anything to do with the drivers (it wasn't a problem on Windows 7 but Windows 10 has a different driver as far as I can tell)

Comment: @CaptainMan Have you ever resolved this / reached more insight in what ClearType does exactly? I have the same problem, and that "choose the best" dialog doesn't really help for the fonts I use most.

Comment: @MrLister ClearType is Microsoft's proprietary tool that handles anti-aliasing by adding colors to make it look nicer. That's a very rough explanation. Either the problem has vanished or (more likely) I have stopped noticing what I thought was blurry. Sorry I don't have a more satisfying answer :(

Comment: @CaptainMan I'm aware of what is _is_, but I still don't know for sure what those 5 screens of choices all do. As you said, one regulates subpixel rendering, but that leaves others where I just have to guess.

Comment: @MrLister My best guess is that each screen is testing a different aspect of it but I am not sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a tool that can setup the parameters individually:
https://github.com/bp2008/BetterClearTypeTuner

The author says that it only exposes settings that actually work and hides non-functional settings.

Comment: This seems like a tool to use to tell what subpixel layout your monitor uses. I am currently on my macbook and cannot tell but I know it also has very small pixels. http://www.lagom.nl/lcd-test/subpixel.php

Comment: @CaptainMan Beware that that subpixel test image (while it's very useful) only works right at _exactly_ DPR=1 (which many computers automatically don't use for higher display resolutions). And the site **does not warn you** if your display is set to anything else. (I'm not yet aware of any way for a website to detect this.) You may have some luck opening his test image in an image editor and setting the editor's view zoomed to 1:1.

Comment: I've deleted a comment regarding a BSOD -- it was unrelated and due to a botched Windows update making driver verification fail.

Comment: \*Correction to my previous comment: it [is possible](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/devicePixelRatio) for a website to correctly display 1:1px images, [even without Javascript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/resolution#dppx). However, the fellow who maintains Lagom.nl has *still* \(as of February 2024\) not written his website to work properly on DPR≠1 systems.

Answer (score 1):

I share your annoyance that there is no *true* answer to this (i.e., a built-in tool to manually configure explicit modes), but "a" solution which I chose is to assign the settings manually, via the registry.

Set `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Avalon.Graphics\<displayName>\PixelStructure` to:

- DWORD `1` for H-RGB (enabled, for most monitors)
- DWORD `2` for H-BGR (enabled, for most televisions)
- DWORD `0` for "flat" (disabled, for most vertical displays)

Source: [ClearType Registry Settings, Desktop Guide, Microsoft Docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/advanced/cleartype-registry-settings)

---

h/t [George Ou from ZDNet](https://www.zdnet.com/article/why-cleartype-doesnt-work-in-portrait-mode/) for a burst bubble as regards V-RGB and V-BGR displays:

> As it turns out, I *wasn't* seeing things; font rendering technology like Windows ClearType won't work in "Portrait" (Vertical) display mode on LCD panels.

h/t [bp2008 from GitHub](https://github.com/bp2008/BetterClearTypeTuner/blob/6fd1bf4624d498bd088d50bb7d55618be9a6300d/README.md#caveats) for a burst bubble as regards setups with displays of differing subpixel orientations:

> [Setting different ClearType settings on different monitors] appears to be entirely non-functional in modern Windows…

Comment: FYI James, there is another answer now that provides a link to a GUI tool that modifies the settings. You may be interested! :)

Comment: @CaptainMan Thanks for publishing that tool! I'll leave my answer here for reference and in case of bitrot. (I actually don't use Windows myself anymore… )